# Jhipster - JWT expired

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, jhipster

I have a Jhipster application that uses JWT as authentication method.
Lately my server started to print repeatdely this error message:

```
com.company.security.jwt.JWTFilter: Security exception for user xxxxxx - JWT expired at 2018-05-03T23:47:49+0000. Current time: 2018-05-04T17:18:28+0000
```

Always with the same user. Usually when a token expires and the user checked the option remember me the token is refreshed.

What could be happening? This specific user is not able to refresh the token and keep sending requests with the expired token?